# DataTables custom date format sorting

Tags: javascript, datatables

I try to sort a custom date format column and all the `dataTables` plugins that I found, doesn't works.

I load the data like this:

HTML:

```
    <table id="task-list" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-title'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-description'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-author'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-status'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-responsible'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-options'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-title'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-description'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-author'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-status'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-responsible'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('th-options'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

and the JS part:

```
$('table#task-list').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json ) {
    $(document).trigger('task.filter.applied',[trigger, target]);
    $(this).show();
}).on('error.dt', function ( e, settings, techNote, message ) {
    alert('error occured');
}).dataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: $(trigger).prop('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: { filterUser: _this.filterUser },
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "author" },
        { "data": "date_created" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": "responsible" },
        { "data": "options" }
    ],  
    "columnDefs": [
        { className: "options", "targets": [-1] },
    ],                              
    "order":[[3,'desc']],
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        $('i.fa[data-dt-action]').tooltip();
        PLUGIN.applyButtonAction({ target: 'i.fa[data-dt-action="edit"]',   fn: 'Task.edit' });
        PLUGIN.applyButtonAction({ target: 'i.fa[data-dt-action="assign"]', fn: 'Task.assign' });
        PLUGIN.applyButtonAction({ target: 'i.fa[data-dt-action="status"]', fn: 'Task.status' });
        PLUGIN.applyButtonAction({ target: 'a[data-dt-action="view"]', fn: 'Task.view' });
    },
    language: Dash.dataTables.language                  
});
```

The date format in the column 4 (index 3) is `dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm` 
Any idea how to sort it correctly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a custom column definition which distinguishes between what the value should be for display and for other purposes.

```
'columns': [{
    ...snip other columns...
    [
        'title': 'Some Column Title',
        'type': 'date', 
        'data': function(row, type) {
            if (type === 'display') {
                return row["YourColumn"]; //or row[index] if you like
            } else {
                return //some parseDate(row["YourColumn"]) function here;
            }
        }
    ],
    ...snip other columns...
}],
```

Where I've got "some parseDate function" you'll need a function that parses that date format into a javascript `Date` object.